# VBA value persistence

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of globally defined variables in my VBA (macro) script. I set values to these in a procedure in my current module. Is there any way to get these values in another procedure present in another module.

Comment: If they are *globally* defined as you say they should already be available to the other routine. How and where have you declared them?

Answer (score 1):

As far as variable declaration goes.

Within a sub - this is only accessible to the sub itself:

```
Sub LocalScope()
    Dim stringVariable as string

    stringVariable = "abc"
    debug.print stringVariable
End Sub
```

Dim at the top of the module - this is accessible to any subs within the module:

```
Dim stringVariable as string

Sub ModuleScope()
    stringVariable = "abc"
End Sub

Sub PrintString()
    debug.print stringVariable
End Sub
```

Public at the top of the module - this is accessible to subs in all modules:

```
Public stringVariable as string

Sub ModuleScope()
    stringVariable = "abc"
End Sub

Sub PrintString()
    debug.print stringVariable
End Sub
```